# Can second order ordinal arithmetic be extended to the same extent as ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

In a prior [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335912/is-zfc-interpretable-in-a-kind-of-an-extended-form-of-second-order-arithmetic), I've posed the idea of reducing set theory to an extended kind of second order ordinal arithmetic $\small \sf`` 2 oO A"$. The idea was to have a domain of ordinals and sets of ordinals where the set of all ordinals is well ordered by relation $<$ denoting ordinal strict smaller than, that have an ordered pairing function on ordinals to ordinals, and that liberally define sets of ordinals after any formula. Thus it can define relations between ordinals as sets of ordinals that are ordered pairs of ordinals. The ordinals are not limited to the naturals, they are extended by axioms of infinity, size and successor cardinals, so that it results in defining all kinds of ordinals that $\small \sf ZFC$ can define. The idea is that the known set theory $\small \sf ZFC$ can be interpreted in this system via building $\sf L$ inside it. Now I'm wondering about if this extended kind of second order ordinal arithmetic can be extended further to the same length $\small \sf ZFC$ set theory can be extended. Can for example the Wholeness axiom be expressed and have the same strength as it is with extending set theory? Thereby playing the same foundation role extensions of $\small \sf ZFC$ has as regards encoding large cardinal properties.

**Wholeness axiom**: there is a non-trivial elementary embedding $j$ from the set of all ordinals to itself, with respect to formulas that doesn't mention $j$.

If we assume that $\small \sf 2 oO A$ interprets $\small \sf ZFC$, then would $\small \sf 2oOA$ plus that wholeness axiom be equi-interpretable with $\small \sf ZFC$+ Wholeness axiom?

Comment: In general your language have the same expressive power as the usual language of set theory. Consider the well-founded graph translation $\tau$ of language of $ZFC$ into your language, which idea is to interpret sets by well-founded extensional binary relations $(A,R)$ with a fixed point $a\in A$ (by Mostowski's transitive collapse theorem there is a unique transitive set $X$ such that  $(A,R)$ and $(X,\in)$ are isomorphic, the whole triple $(A,R,a)$ encodes the set $f(a)$, where $f$ is the isomorphism). The translations of $=$ and $\in$ are naturally defined according to this understanding.

Comment: Then, in order to obtain an extension of your theory corresponding to some $T\subseteq ZFC$, you just add to your base theory all $\tau(\varphi)$, for axioms $\varphi$ of $T$.

Comment: I want an extension of my theory corresponding to some $T \supseteq ZFC$

Comment: It was a typo, should have been $T\supseteq ZFC$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov, I think I got what you mean, you interpret sets after graphs, and the later are encoded by sets of ordered pairs of ordinals, etc... I didn't work out the details, of course this way we get to extend this theory as far as ZF can go by brute translation force. However, I'm interested if we can extend this arithmetic naively without such  explicit translations in mind, and whether those extensions can work to be as strong as those of ZFC. Look at the wholeness axiom, it doesn't mention any such translation, but it might turn to be equivalent to the one extending set theory.

Comment: Your theory should be bi-interpretable with the theory $U=(ZFC-\mathit{Power})+\forall x\exists y (|x|<|y|)+\mathit{ZermeloTheorem}$. The bi-interpration would consist of the  $\tau\colon U \triangleleft \mathsf{2oOA}$ (as above) and $\iota\colon \mathsf{2oOA} \triangleleft U$ (that is a straightforward interpretation of $\mathsf{2oOA}$ in $U$ that interpretes ordinals as ordinals and sets of ordinals as sets of ordinals). So your theory is essentially the same as $U$.

Comment: And using this bi-interpretation it is easy to see that your systems + wholeness axiom is bi-interpretable with $U$ + wholeness axiom. So the real question is whether your wholeness axiom would imply powerset axiom over $U$. Because, if it would, then $U$+wholeness axiom would be equal to $ZFC$+ wholeness axiom.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov If your "equi"-interpretability is correct, then according to the answer in this posting: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338242/is-the-power-set-axiom-essential-for-constructing-l?rq=1, **$\small \sf L$** would be interpretable in $\small \sf 2oOA$, thus the latter would be equi-interpretable with $\small \sf ZFC$. I think this would be enough to get $\small \sf 2oOA$ + wholeness axiom equi-interpretable with ZFC+wholeness axiom.

Comment: Note that bi-interpretability is stronger than mutual interpretability. Namely, the requrement is that sellf interpretations $\tau\circ\iota\colon U\triangleleft U$ and $\iota\circ\tau\colon \nathsf{2oOA}$ should be definably isomorphic to identity interpretations. Bi-interpretability between theories $T$, $V$ implies one-to-one correspondence between lattices of their extensions. My construction indeed should imply formalizability of $L$ in your ordinal theory. And since your self-embedding axiom implies that you have the same kind of self-embedding in $L$, it should indeed be enough.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov, Is this bi-interpretability of $\sf 2oOA$ with $U$ something that you are sure of? If so then this would mean that $\sf 2oOA$ can interpret $ZFC$ through $L$. In a prior posting you said that you don't have a full proof of that? do you have it now? I mean through $\tau$. If so then this would answer the prior posting! Wouldn't it?